# How do I register API environment for Datastore in GAE Flexible Environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-flexible, google-flexible

When trying to run Datastore in a Servlet in Google App Engine Flexible Environment I get "No API environment is registered for this thread." (Details below.)

I see questions on StackOverflow about this happening in local machines or unit tests, but this is happening in GAE in a regular Servlet.

Here is the entirety of my Datastore code, a simple query. Do I need to register an API environment? If so, how?

```
List<String> kinds = new ArrayList<String>();
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService(DatastoreServiceConfig.Builder                         .withImplicitTransactionManagementPolicy(ImplicitTransactionManagementPolicy.NONE));

PreparedQuery global = datastore.prepare(new Query("__kind__"));
for (Entity globalStat : global.asIterable()) {
   String kindName = globalStat.getKey().getName();
   kinds.add(kindName);
}
```

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: No API environment is registered for this thread.
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppId(DatastoreApiHelper.java:180)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppIdNamespace(DatastoreApiHelper.java:196)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.<init>(Query.java:208)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.<init>(Query.java:139)
    at ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the datastore under Flexible environment you need to use the [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-cloud-datastore)
You can use the [Compat enviroment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-jetty9-and-apis) if you want to use the datastore using "old" APIs

Comment: Thank you  Shay. There sure are a lot of  different APIs  into Google Datastore! Client API, AppEngine API, etc.

Just going by  package name, we have com.google.datastore(.v1),  com.google.cloud.datastore, and com.google.appengine.api.datastore.

Comment: Hello! Clould you please show us the source of this information?

Comment: @RodrigoBorba this is pretty old info, but still under flex you need to use the Official Google Cloud Libs and not the ones that comes with the AppEngine SDK